# Preserving the input size using Ghostscript for EPS to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, eps

I would like to batch convert multiple EPS to PDF using Ghostscript. I can't seem to find the right option to preserve my input EPS size while using

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=ALL.pdf *.eps
```

it outputs to the default A4 paper size, I don't like to specify the size using `-sPAPERSIZE=a[X]` and just want to let the gs leave the output size as is in input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `-dEPSCrop`.

EPS files specifically don't contain any media size requests so if you don't tell GS what size media to use, it has to use its default.

Comment: I see, tnx for the answer @KenS